# DriveItem Preview returns "Hmm... looks like this file does not have a preview we can show"

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I am using Microsoft Graph to preview an item stored in SharePoint.

I tried the [driveItem: preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0) API and I am getting a URL return like this:

```
https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/embed.aspx?uniqueId={guid}&access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...
```

But when I am rendering it into a `div`, then it is showing this error:

> "Hmm... looks like this file does not have a preview we can show"

[image]

Below is the code from the `.aspx` page:

```js
function OpenDocument(fileURL, filename) {
    var path = filename;
    var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, path.length).toLowerCase();

    var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" class=\"{CP}\">";  //Add class if PDF file is uploaded 
    object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href=\"{FileName}\" target = \"_blank\">here</a>";
    object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
    object += "</object>";
    object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, fileURL);

    var iframe = '';

    if (ext == 'pdf') { //Add class if PDF file is uploaded 
        object = object.replace(/{CP}/g, "clsPdf");  //G16052017
        $("#dialogContent").html(object);
    }
    else {
        iframe += "<embed src='" + fileURL + "' />";
        $("#dialogContent").html(iframe);
    }

    ShowDocumentPopup();
    return false;
}
```

I have also passed the preview URI to an embedded tag and with an `iframe` but neither worked.

Is this an HTML rendering issue or does SharePoint have some limitations in showing previews for images?

*NOTE: I have added a fake Preview URL for your reference, just to show you the format of the URL sent by Preview API.*

Answer (score 0):

The documentation isn't very clear but it was my understanding that the "preview" endpoint was more indented for embedding document previews. What you're describing sounds more like a file thumbnail and there *is* a specific endpoint for that: [List thumbnails for a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-thumbnails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). This returns a set of file thumbnails for a given file:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "small": { "height": 64, "width": 96, "url": "https://sn3302files..."},
      "medium": { "height": 117, "width": 176, "url": "https://sn3302files..."},
      "large": { "height": 533, "width": 800, "url": "https://sn3302files..."}
    }
  ]
}
```

You can also request the thumbnail content via the API:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/thumbnails/{thumb-id}/{size}/content
```